# Limiting height of element and using scrollbars

Tags: css

What should be easy has got me stumped.  I would like to lists side by side.  They both must be limited to 200px tall, and if one or both are talker, a stroll bar will be shown.  Can anyone help? Thanks

```
<style>
#child {float: right;}
#container {height: 200px;overflow: hidden;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
 <div id="child">
  <ul id="list2"><li>One</li><li>Two</li><li>Three</li><li>One</li><li>Two</li><li>Three</li><li>One</li><li>Two</li><li>Three</li><li>One</li><li>Two</li><li>Three</li><li>One</ul>
 </div>
 <div id="parent">
  <ul id="list1"><li>One</li><li>Two</li><li>Three</li><li>One</li><li>Three</li><li>One</li><li>Three</li><li>One</li><li>Two</li><li>Three</li><li>One</li><li>Two</li><li>Three</li><li>One</li><li>Two</li><li>Three</li><li>One</ul>
 </div>
</div>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to use is `overflow-y: auto`